# How to implement search tool bar to search for queries and display list of suggestions in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, search, search-engine

how does search tool work? When user enters queries to search and some suggestions are displayed based on queries.

Answer (score 1):

Did you search for any example? This is a very well-known area for all platforms and languages. just search for the term "auto suggest c#"